# Understanding max_features parameter in RandomForestRegressor

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-selection

While constructing each tree in the random forest using bootstrapped samples, for each terminal node, we select m variables at random from p variables to find the best split (p is the total number of features in your data). My questions (for RandomForestRegressor) are:

1) What does max_features correspond to (m or p or something else)?

2) Are m variables selected at random from max_features variables (what is the value of m)?

3) If max_features corresponds to m, then why would I want to set it equal to p for regression (the default)? Where is the randomness with this setting (i.e., how is it different from bagging)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Straight from the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#parameters):

> [`max_features`] is the size of the random subsets of features to consider when splitting a node.

So `max_features` is what you call *m*. When `max_features="auto"`, *m* = *p* and no feature subset selection is performed in the trees, so the "random forest" is actually a bagged ensemble of ordinary regression trees. The docs go on to say that

> Empirical good default values are `max_features=n_features` for regression problems, and `max_features=sqrt(n_features)` for classification tasks

By setting `max_features` differently, you'll get a "true" random forest.

Comment: So why do they claim that "Empirical good default values are max_features=n_features for regression problems"? As you say this is just bagging - isn't random forest supposed to be better than bagging?

Comment: @csankar69: I'm no expert in regression trees. I did work on the RFs because I use them for classification, and I can assure you their author is knowledgeable in these matters. In any case, you can check for yourself whether attribute bagging helps for your problem.

Comment: I'm 95% sure the max_features=n_features for regression is a mistake on scikit's part. The original paper for RF gave max_features = n_features/3 for regression. It wouldn't even make sense to use the former, it's not even a RF.

Comment: Thanks @UlysseMizrah for the comment! [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#From_bagging_to_random_forests) references *The Elements of Statistical Learning: 2nd Edition* (Hastie et. al. 2009, p. 592), which reports that the original authors recommend n_features / 3. I thought I'd post these additional references just in case someone was interested.

Comment: @MatthewGunn so absent any justification from the sklearn author, for `RandomForestRegressor`, we "should" have that `max_features="auto"` ⇒ `max_features=int(n_features / 3.0)` ?

Comment: The 'per split' language has always confused me. max_features should be the number of features that are considered when constructing each decision tree, not just on a per-split level, right? I.e. each decision tree is made with the same features, instead of sampling different features per split.

Comment: The question whether `max_features=n_features` makes a good default is discussed in depth on https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/324370/295421 and https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7254

Comment: So each tree in random forest select subset of features and from there use max_features for each node (in this case max_feature=n_features should still be considered RF) or RF refers to selecting all features then using subset of features at each node?

Comment: Ah I found the answer, from https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/random-forest-feature-subsets.html for those interested.

Answer (score 9):

@lynnyi, max_features is the number of features that are considered on a per-split level, rather than on the entire decision tree construction. More clear, during the construction of each decision tree, RF will still use all the features (n_features), but it only consider number of "max_features" features for node splitting. And the "max_features" features are randomly selected from the entire features. You could confirm this by plotting one decision tree from a RF with max_features=1, and check all the nodes of that tree to count the number of features involved.

Comment: This is more like a comment to another comment than an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry but right now I have less than 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: wait so each tree in random forest actually uses all features however randomly select subset of them at each node? Or does each tree take subset of features and from there take max_features at each node?

Comment: @ Ambleu, "each tree in random forest actually uses all features however randomly select subset of them at each node" is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

max_features is basically the number of features selected at random and without replacement at split. Suppose you have 10 independent columns or features, then max_features=5 will select at random and without replacement 5 features at every split.