# Does feature importance change with number of max_features selected in a RandomForestRegressor, scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-selection

In one of my projects, I was trying to determine which of my 12 features are the most driving factors against a target variable using RandomForestRegressor(sklearn). RandomForest nicely gives you a list of feature importances that explains which of the features is best used to explain the target. But I'm still unsure about what should be the max_features for my model because the default answer is use all features which would mean my model is just bagged ensemble of trees. After going through some [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939750/understanding-max-features-parameter-in-randomforestregressor) , it made sense to use n/3 as maximum number of features if you really looking for a random forest of trees. I continued with n/3 as maximum number of features because I was getting pretty good r-square.
Very recently I realized that my feature importances are completely different when I changed the max_features to n. If feature importances are really relative to each other on a scale of 1-10, can it really increment/does it make sense to increment from 0.36 to 0.81 when I change number of features from n/3 to n? So what should be the max_features if I'm trying to determine the most explanatory variable given that I'm getting pretty good r-square with both n/3 and n. I'm unable to figure out what I'm missing.[image]Please suggest how to proceed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

**First scenario:**

Assume that there are two features `feat1`, and `feat2` which provide the same type of information to the model. Now if both are present in the data, and the model picks one first, the importance of `feat1` will be large. Now the model analyzes the second feature `feat2` and concludes that it doesn't provide any significant increase in knowledge than already provided by `feat1`. So the importance of `feat2` will be relatively small.

**Second scenario:**

You changed the `max_features` to `n/3` and somehow `feat1` is now not considered. So the information provided by `feat2` is now greater than before. So its importance can increase significantly.

Note that this is for a single model. I don't know how it affects the whole ensemble. And maybe you will be able to get more details on https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: In your first scenario, why is model(every decision tree) picking up feat1 first everytime before feat2? In the second scenario, isn't there a case where feat2 isn't considered and feat1 is explaining the information that feat2 can explain? My question is more of "How are these values really feature importances on a relative scale (given all of them sum to 1) if they keep changing drastically with change in number of features?"

Comment: @ThReSholD The averaging is done at the end. Secondly, the feature_importance is calculated after using all samples, not sample by sample.