# Random Forest - Max Features

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I do have a question and I need your support. I have a data set which I am analyzing. I need to predict a target. To do this I did some data cleaning, among others drop highly (linear correlated feautes)

After preparing my data I applied random forest regressor (it is a regression problem). I am stucked a bit, since I really cannot catch the meaning and thus the value for **max_features**

I found the following page [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939750/understanding-max-features-parameter-in-randomforestregressor/23950648#23950648), where it is written

> features=n_features for regression is a mistake on scikit's part. The original paper for RF gave max_features = n_features/3 for regression

I do get different results if I use max_features=sqrt(n) or max_features=n_features

Can any1 give me a good explanation how to approach this parameter?

That would be really great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_features` is a parameter that needs to be tuned. Values such as `sqrt` or `n/3` are defaults and usually perform decently, but the parameter needs to be optimized for every dataset, as it will depend on the features you have, their correlations and importances.

Therefore, I suggest training the model many times with a grid of values for `max_features`, trying every possible value from 2 to the total number of your features. 
 Train your `RandomForestRegressor` with `oob_score=True` and use `oob_score_` to assess the performance of the Forest. Once you have looped over all possible values of `max_features`, keep the one that obtained the highest `oob_score`.

For safety, keep the `n_estimators` on the high end.

PS: this procedure is basically a grid search optimization for one parameter, and is usually done via Cross Validation. Since RFs give you OOB scores, you can use these instead of CV scores, as they are quicker to compute.